# Polymer paper-dropdown-menu not appearing correctly

Tags: html, polymer

I'm trying to set up some Polymer modules for a project I'm working on. In the code below, the button works just fine but when I import the dropdown, it appears weirdly. This code comes straight from the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@polymer/paper-dropdown-menu), but doesn't work. I suspect that I'm missing a dependency, but it's not mentioned anywhere in the docs.
Thanks!

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="module" src="/node_modules/@polymer/paper-button/paper-button.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/node_modules/@polymer/paper-dropdown-menu/paper-dropdown-menu.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/node_modules/@polymer/paper-item/paper-item.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="/node_modules/@polymer/paper-listbox/paper-listbox.js"></script>
</head>
  <body>
    <paper-button raised class="indigo">raised</paper-button>
    <paper-dropdown-menu label="Dinosaurs">
      <paper-listbox slot="dropdown-content" class="dropdown-content">
        <paper-item>allosaurus</paper-item>
        <paper-item>brontosaurus</paper-item>
        <paper-item>carcharodontosaurus</paper-item>
        <paper-item>diplodocus</paper-item>
      </paper-listbox>
    </paper-dropdown-menu>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbKcS.png)

Answer (score 0):

What exactly is the class="dropdown-content" doing in the paper-listbox element?

Comment: No idea. I just copy/pasted what was in the docs.